# How to disable past dates with respect to specific date in materialize datepicker & vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I am unable to disable the past dates from a specific date like 01/01/1970 **

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    yearRange: [1970, 2010],
    defaultDate: new Date(1970, 1, 0),
    minDate: new Date(1970, 0, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2010, 11, 31),
  });
});
```

Comment: What does `unable to disable` mean? Please attach a screenshot and/or describe what is displayed.

Comment: Actually, I want to enable all the dates ranging from Jan 1st, 1970 to Dec 31st, 2010, that's why I put the yearRange from 1970 to 2010 in the jquery code of datepicker. But the problem is that the user can select the date before 01/01/1970 like Dec 5th, 1969 or May 12th, 1968 etc, but I want that user can select the date range from 1970 to 2010 only. The above code is not disabling the dates before 1970 & after 2010. So please tell me how to do that. minDate & maxDate are not working properly here...please find out the solution for me...thanks.

Comment: I've just copied your code and included materialize datepicker and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/px0djq8w/

Comment: @Johannes, thanks for your quick reply. Okay, it worked for me as well, but here I also want that if a user clicks the back button of the calendar while he is on January 1970, then the back arrow button should not be clickable so that the calendar screen doesn't change backward and in this case next arrow button should be clickable. In the same way if user is on December 2010, then the next arrow button should not be clickable so that the calendar screen should not move ahead further and back arrow button should be clickable. Is this possible. If yes, how to do that, please tell me the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the error of your original question (see https://jsfiddle.net/px0djq8w/). Nevertheless, I think I found a solution for the second issue your mentioned in the comments.

First, add the `minYear` and `maxYear` to the datepicker initialization options. It looks like the Datepicker code is not using the `minDate`/`maxDate` for this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        // ...
        minYear: 1970,
        maxYear: 2010   
    });
  });
```

Second, we need to fix two things in the Materialize Datepicker library because two things are missing in my opinion:

1. There already is an `.is-disabled` class for the `previous` and `next` buttons that is added to the `next` button. 
   The issue now is that for the `previous` button the check if it should be disabled or not is happening too late (after the button is declared, ~ line 9241). This is how it should look like instead:

```js
if (isMinYear && (month === 0 || opts.minMonth >= month)) {
  prev = false;
}

var leftArrow = '<svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.41 16.09l-4.58-4.59 4.58-4.59L14 5.5l-6 6 6 6z"/><path d="M0-.5h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>';
        html += "<button class=\"month-prev" + (prev ? '' : ' is-disabled') + "\" type=\"button\">" + leftArrow + "</button>";
```

2. There is now CSS rule that tells the browser what to do with a button that `.is-disabled`. You need to add this rule after importing the CSS of the library:

```css
button.is-disabled {
  visibility: hidden; // hide button
  pointer-events: none; // disable clicks
}
```

Link to GitHub issue: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/6541

Comment: I appreciate your tremendous effort. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work? If yes, please mark this answer as approved to help others to find the right solution. If not, feel free to ask!